# ConstraintViolationException with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am fighting with a ConstraintViolationException (a copy of the complete exception you find at the bottom) since the last 4 hours. I tried several ways to get rid of but I either end in new exceptions or nothing changed. Would be super great if you can help me here, please.

I give you here a model of my implementation so that it is easy for you to see my dependencies. Every class has getter and setters for each field as well as @Entity, equals, and hashcode. I just omit them here.

The Problem appears after these steps:

- Application starts
- Create some BigBosses with a storage Different
- Workers are created added to the list of each BigBoss.
- At the same time in the CTOR of Workers, one Robot is created and receive the reference to its worker
- The Application is running for some time
- Storing the BigBossses in the bigBossRepository
- Application terminates
- Application re-establishing
- Loading the BigBosses from the bigBossRepository
- call bigBossRepository.deleteAll()
- Application runs
- **Storing the BigBossses in the bigBossRepository**
- **EXCEPTION**

So in short: After storing, delete and try to store again the same BigBosses in the Databases cause the exception. I need this process of delete and add again, so there is no way to just ignore that exception. I just SpringBoot, Hibernate and CrudRepositories.

Moreover: If I delete the relationship between the Robot and the Worker and make @Transient Robot and create just a new Robot in the default CTOR of Worker at every re-run process then it works fine. So the problem must be between the Robot and the Worker relationship.

My Implementation:

**BigBossABC**

```
public abstract class BigBossABC {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long bigBossABC_id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bigBossAbc", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<WorkerABC> workerABCList = new LinkedList<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Storage storage;

    //default CTOR
    public BigBossABC() {
    }

    public BigBossABC(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
    }
}
```

**BigBoss**

```
public class BigBoss extends BigBossABC{

    public BigBoss(Storage storage) {
        super(storage);
    }
}
```

**WorkerABC**

```
public abstract class WorkerABC {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long workerabc_id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    BigBossABC bigBossAbc;


    public WorkerABC(BigBossABC bigBossABC) {
        this.bigBossABC = bigBossABC;
    }

    //default CTOR
    public WorkerABC() {
    }
}
```

**Worker**

```
 public class Worker extends WorkerABC {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Robot robot;

    public Worker(BigBossABC bigBossABC) {
        super(bigBossABC);
        this.robot = new Robot(this);
    }

    //default CTOR
    public Worker() {
    }
}
```

**Robot**

```
public class Robot {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long robot_id;

    @OneToOne
    Worker workerImpl;

    public Robot(Worker workerImpl) {
        this.workerImpl = workerImpl;
    }

    //default CTOR
    public Robot() {
    }
}
```

**Storage**

```
public class Storage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long storage_id;

    //default CTOR
    public Storage() {
    }
}
```

**BigBossRepo**

```
@Repository
public interface BigBossRepo extends CrudRepository<BigBossABC, Long> {
}
```

**Exception short:**

> could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint
>   ["FK9E0KTPD13MOT29V2J32CG8NAM: PUBLIC.ROBOT FOREIGN
>   KEY(WORKER_WORKER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.WORKERABC(WORKER_ID) (1)"; SQL
>   statement: insert into robot (id, worker_worker_id) values (null, ?)
>   [23506-194]]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

**Whole log:**

```
2017-06-17 22:02:15.420  WARN 11268 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23506, SQLState: 23506
2017-06-17 22:02:15.420 ERROR 11268 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Referentielle Integrität verletzt: "FK9E0KTPD13MOT29V2J32CG8NAM: PUBLIC.ROBOT FOREIGN KEY(WORKER_WORKER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.WORKERABC(WORKER_ID) (1)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK9E0KTPD13MOT29V2J32CG8NAM: PUBLIC.ROBOT FOREIGN KEY(WORKER_WORKER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.WORKERABC(WORKER_ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
insert into robot (id, worker_worker_id) values (null, ?) [23506-194]]
2017-06-17 22:02:15.433 ERROR 11268 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FK9E0KTPD13MOT29V2J32CG8NAM: PUBLIC.ROBOT FOREIGN KEY(WORKER_WORKER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.WORKERABC(WORKER_ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
insert into robot (id, worker_worker_id) values (null, ?) [23506-194]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referentielle Integrität verletzt: "FK9E0KTPD13MOT29V2J32CG8NAM: PUBLIC.ROBOT FOREIGN KEY(WORKER_WORKER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.WORKERABC(WORKER_ID) (1)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK9E0KTPD13MOT29V2J32CG8NAM: PUBLIC.ROBOT FOREIGN KEY(WORKER_WORKER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.WORKERABC(WORKER_ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
insert into robot (id, worker_worker_id) values (null, ?) [23506-194]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowOwnTable(ConstraintReferential.java:371) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:313) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:976) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:994) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:161) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146) ~[h2-1.4.194.jar:1.4.194]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2855) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3426) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaMergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaMergeEventListener.java:56) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:235) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:832) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:260) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:232) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:832) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:260) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:511) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:542) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.trademerger.controller.web.LogoutController.logout(LogoutController.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test2;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: What verssion of spring are you using?

Comment: SpringBoot 1.5.3

Comment: I was thinking about [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-137), but your spring version has the fix. Add `orphanRemoval = true` to `@OneToOne`

Comment: orphan is per default true.

Comment: seems false to me
`/**
     * (Optional) Whether to apply the remove operation to entities that have
     * been removed from the relationship and to cascade the remove operation to
     * those entities.
     * @since Java Persistence 2.0
     */
    boolean orphanRemoval() default false;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowing duplicates? this issue comes when there are duplicates. Also , when deleting, is it deleting the whole relationship chain? 
Since when you try to add next, it should not see any duplicates in the related tables.
Hibernate wont handle duplicates, you need to handle it using code , handle duplicates/ handle exceptions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Since I call deleteAll at the repository I actually expect that everything gets deleted. The docu of CrudRepository says so.

Answer (score 0):

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

If you add this annotation to your test class, the h2 database is reset before each test. I had the same issue, and this solved it for me. I got ConstraintViolationExceptions on values that shouldn't even be in the database at that point, so I made sure they weren't.